# infinte loop in angular expression binding

Tags: angular, promise

So I am new to angular 4 and am trying to bind a function to an html element that will then call a service. The problem is that it introduces an infinite loop. After a little research I believe it is due to the digest cycle. I think using promises would resolve the issue but I need some please! Here is what I got so far.

In my HTML:

```
<h1> {{ getElement('title') }}</h1>
```

and the function in component.js file:

```
getElement(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.NewCmsService.getLang().subscribe.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data) // infinite loop starts here
        })
        return this.element;
    }
```

Also I am not using typescript as an FYI. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Angular runs a new change detection cycle every time an asynchronous function returns -- therefore, **each time your service returns**. Then, on each change detection cycle, it attempts to update your view and rebinds everything, effectively rerunning any code you have placed as the target of your binding. Because you are then subscribing **again** in the function that is called when rerunning the binding code, Angular decides to run **another** change detection cycle because the service returns again.

Long story short: **Do not place async logic in any function that is bound to an html element.**

Honestly, you shouldn't be putting complex logic in bindings at all, because then they run every change detection cycle (which is a lot). I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but I don't know why you would ever need to do what you are doing.